# Specific values from sliders

Tags: javascript

I got some problem with syntax, I'm newbie so maybe it can be fixed by another method.

I've started in changing this code: 
[Pricing Slider by amirolahmad](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-pricing-slider-donations)

All I want to get is this thing: [Table with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWWrk.jpg)

For example if you put on slider $amount value 1555 and on slider $duration value 2012 -> 
$total, at the bottom must show 1000.

Here is part how I understand it for first Column:

```
$total = "$" + (10);
if ($amount <= 1199 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (100);}
else if (1499 >= $amount >= 1199 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (500);}
else if (1999 >= $amount >= 1500 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (900);}
else if (2499 >= $amount >= 2000 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (1300);}
else if (2999 >= $amount >= 2500 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (1700);}
else if (3499 >= $amount >= 3000 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (2100);}
else if (3999 >= $amount >= 3500 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (2500);}
else if ($amount >= 4000 && $duration >= 2016) {$total = (2900);}
```

If i will input this between lines 44 and 60, I cant get satisfying results. 
Is it possible to do this on "else if"? or i need to do array or something?

Kind Regards, js newbie.

Comment: I'm guessing you want amount to be between a set of values for your else statements, so `1499 >= $amount >= 1199` is not the correct syntax for that try `$amount <= 1499 && $amount >= 1200` for those parts.

Comment: I will check it. will be back in few minutes thx :)

Comment: it works :D thank You, i will repeat it for another columns, if any questions I will ask here again.

Comment: fixed all of my currently problems :> thanks Dymos. At this time we can close this topic.